# Why do left/right/bottom/up attributes work with default static position?

Tags: html, css

I'm reading about CSS Position on [Mozilla CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

Definition for static

> **static**
>
> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document. The top, right, bottom, left, and z-index properties
>   have no effect. This is the default value.

Definition for relative:

> **relative**
>
> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the
>   document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of
>   top, right, bottom, and left.

As I understand: (correct me if I was wrong)

- static is default
- left/right/bottom/up ... has no effect on static element.

But when I code CSS, I often don't put "position: ..." inside. I also use left/right/bottom/up attributes and I see it works. Is there any wrong with my understanding ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct, positions are static by default. Maybe it could be the software changing the default positions of your elements? Try playing around with position : relative or position : absolute and see whether there are any changes, if no changes happen to the elements then that means they might have been given a different default position value

Comment: Maybe you are using a browser that not follow standards or have a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In standards-conformant user agents, elements are statically positioned by default and styling statically positioned elements with top/left/etc will have no effect.

The example below should demonstrate this. While both squares have `left: 150px`, only the relatively positioned green one will obey it. The red one is statically positioned by default.

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 150px;
}
.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.relative { position: relative; }
```

```html
<div class="square red"></div>
<div class="square green relative"></div>
```

If the two squares are stacked perfectly on top of each other when viewing the example above, you're not using a standards-conformant browser (or have some settings adjusted or a custom stylesheet in place).

Depending on your environment, setup, framework, etc, there might be a baseline stylesheet that is applying relative positioning to elements before your custom styles take effect.

But to answer your question, what you've read in the MDN Docs is correct and consistent with how most browsers behave.